# Define a repo logo via terraform github_repository

Tags: terraform, github

Is there a way to give my terraformed github_repository a custom logo?

The [doc](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/github/r/repository.html) doesn't have a field for it, but is there an undocumented feature?

Branding is important!

Comment: Welcome to DevOps.SE.  If the feature doesn't exist, maybe you should submit a feature request at https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-github/issues .